# fileproviderd and rtcreportingd spiking cpu

Tags: macos, performance

could use some advice from experts. For awhile now, the fileproviderd and rtcreportingd processes are both spiking on my 2017 macbook pro. I'm on Ventura 13.3.1 (a).

I've done some investigation, and the only thing I find are articles or posts talking about how fileproviderd helps syncing the file system with cloud providers. Key culprits called out that I use are Dropbox, Google Drive, and iCloud Drive.

I mainly use iCloud drive for image syncing, and basic file syncing, and can totally live without it, so I've disabled it.

I am in the process of switching from Dropbox premium to Google Drive/One, hence both being used. However, in trying to resolve this issue, I have disconnected Google Drive, and have exited out of it ( I don't see any processes running named Google drive or anything similar).

I have Dropbox syncing temporarily disabled, I exited dropbox, and killed the Dropbox File Provider process.

However, both fileproviderd and rtcreportingd both are still spiking.

I found another article that mentioned restarting in safe mode, which I tried, and even then, the two processes spiked, despite Dropbox and Google Drive not auto starting.

In Console, I see a ton of errors for fileproviderd that repeat constantly (excerpt below) but I'm unable to find any useful information when googling.

```
error   22:39:21.034271-0700    fileproviderd   ┳2157dc ‼️  done executing <FS694f ‼️  materialize(fileID(12910465465)) why:materialization|diskImportDone sched:utility#1684301960.999319 error:<NSError: libfssync.MaterializationError 3 "materializationFailed" >>
```

I'm at a loss for next steps... At this point, I'm concerned for 1) my battery, as it lasts all of 45 minutes due to the cpu spikin continuously, and potential longer term damage due to the heat and constant stress on the laptop.

Any pointers or recommendations would be greatly appreciated! TYIA!!

Answer (score 1):

Tresorit can spike fileproviderd. Took a lot of trial and error to figure this out, as Tresorit runs a hidden daemon which doesn't show up in LaunchControl.

[image: Tresorit record in Console]

For those who don't know Tresorit, it's a file sync service like Dropbox but more secure. It's supposed to be E2E zeroknowledge sync.

Turning off Finder integrations of various kinds in Tresorit preferences helped. I have not yet removed Tresorit from my machine (I will, chose NextCloud instead). This is on an Intel Mac Mini i5 running Monterey 12.6.7.

NextCloud, MegaSync did not spike fileproviderd (probably don't use it).

Apparently Dropbox and OneDrive also use Apple's fileproviderd agent. Check them carefully if you use them and face extended fileproviderd spikes.